# Windows Server 2012 R2 shared folder

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, shared-storage

On Windows Server 2012 R2 I have a shared folder that I can map on 30 other computers only. Is that a license issue or just missed settings?
Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Check the properties of the share > User Limit.

Comment: Hi Greg! Thanks for the answer. I have done it. There is no limit. In net config server I see the maximum logged on users: 30, maybe this is the problem? Is that changeable?

Comment: What is the output of `wmic os get OperatingSystemSKU`

Comment: What happens when you try to map it on the 31st computer?

Comment: The output is 33, on the 31st computer the error message is "No more connections can be made at this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept."